# how can I do numeric pagination?

Tags: pagination

How can I do numeric pagination?

```
<?php
        $args4 = array('post_type' => 'post', 'showposts' => 99, 'cat' => 23);
        $loop4 = new WP_Query($args4);
        while ($loop4->have_posts()) : $loop4->the_post();
        ?>
            <article class="cover-image ds s-overlay post type-post status-publish format-status has-post-thumbnail">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div><!-- .post-thumbnail -->
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_email(), '100'); ?>

                    <h3 class="entry-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>

                    <!-- .entry-meta -->
                </header>
                <!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p></p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fs-14 color-main"></i>
                        <time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2018-09-18T15:15:12+00:00"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article><!-- #post-## -->
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        <nav class="navigation pagination " role="navigation">

        </nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Deleopment. What have you achieved so far? please show some effort (edit your question and tel others what have your done so far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot af possibilities. I use for few years this method :

```
$all_post = get_posts($args);
$nb_ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');
$nb_post = count($all_post);
$nb_page = ceil($nb_post / $nb_ppp);
$current_page = (!empty(get_query_var('paged'))) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args['offset'] = ($current_page == 1) ? 0 : (($current_page - 1) * $nb_ppp);
$args['numberposts'] = $nb_ppp;
$current_posts = get_posts($args);
```

All informations to create pagination : 
 - Number of pages
 - Current page
 - Base link url (miss)

I hope you use a taxonomy to liste your posts :

```
global $wp_query;
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$base_link = get_term_link($term);
```

Or a basic page model :

```
global $post;
$base_link = get_permalink($post->ID);
```

You can create a simple loop (for ...).

```
$link = $base_link.'/page/'.$i;
```

Enjoy.